# Is there anyway to activate numpad on MacBook Pro?

Tags: mac, macbook, macbook-pro, numpad

How do we activate the [numeric keypad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_keypad) on a MacBook Pro?

The <kbd>Fn</kbd> key doesn't seem to work. Neither does <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer model Macbook (Pro)s don't have numpads, I think since they changed the F-key assignments so that `F6` had a special function.